# Linux system-call interface

Tags: linux, driver, freebsd, system-calls

So, I'm moving from FreeBSD to Linux for driver writing and I have a two part question.

In FreeBSD, there is the [following](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/sys/sysent.h?v=FREEBSD10) :

```
struct sysent {                 /* system call table */
   int     sy_narg;        /* number of arguments */
   sy_call_t *sy_call;     /* implementing function */
   au_event_t sy_auevent;  /* audit event associated with syscall */
   systrace_args_func_t sy_systrace_args_func; 
   /* optional argument conversion function. */
   u_int32_t sy_entry;     /* DTrace entry ID for systrace. */
   u_int32_t sy_return;    /* DTrace return ID for systrace. */
   u_int32_t sy_flags;     /* General flags for system calls. */
   u_int32_t sy_thrcnt;
   };
```

Now, when I write a driver or whatever, I can fill that out and have a system call available to userspace through the `SYSCALL_MODULE(9)`.

In userspace, I can use:

`int mod_find(const char *)`, `mod_stat(int mod_id, module_stat *)`, and 
`syscall(int syscall_num, [args])`

functions to find, get details on, and execute an arbitrary system call.

I know in Linux that we have `syscall(2)`, but do we have functions to find system call numbers? Also, how would I make my module available to userspace to even call it?

**EDIT:** I've done some reading and I know that I can alter [`syscall_64.tbl`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl); however, this is static and I want something that I can do dynamically and not necessiarly through `/dev`.

Comment: I suggest you check out the [The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html).

Comment: I guess for runtime polling you have to parse /usr/include/sys/syscall.h.